# Name and values: single cells vs. range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem using named range in Excel.

If I create a named range using a cell range, I can obtain also a value.

If I select the same cell, one by one using mouse, I haven't anymore an associated value.

[image: As you can see, I have "{...}" as value for all the range select one by one and not using a range]

I have tried also to use VBA, and the result is the same.

Have you some idea to obtain values using multiple cells (without using single range)?

Result expected:
I'm expect to see cell values of the single cells.
- As you can see, if I choose every single cell (A2,A3,A4), Excel doesn't display me the value of these cells inside the name box.
- If I choose a single range (A2:A4), I can see the value of these cells.

How can I display the value of these cells inside Name instead of {...}

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data and expected results. As is, you question is unclear.

Comment: Ok, I've improved my question

Comment: If the values are adjacent you'll get to see the first few values (as many as fit into that window) in the following order: left to righ and then top to bottom. If they are not adjacent you'll just get to see `{...}`. So, either you ensure that the values are next to one another (in the correct order) or you design your own little form to show what you want to see (and not only partial data of which some is obscured).